# Почему не навешивается класс active?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.navig a');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.navig {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navig">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Project name</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p class="lead">Гланая страница</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в браузер по ссылке загружается другая страница, на которой никакого клика не было.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.navig a');

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active');
    }
    this.classList.add('active');
  })
}
```

```css
.navig {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navig">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Project name</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
    <p class="lead">Гланая страница</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Теряется контекст, используй стрелочную функцию

Comment: Это что значит?